# Node JS with Socket IO Winston Logger not outputting debug

Tags: node.js, debugging, logging, socket.io, winston

I'm trying to have the winston logging output logger.debug for a node.js/socket.io project I'm working on but I can't get the debug to show up in the console.

I create logger with:

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)()
        ]
    });
```

On connection I'm trying to get the the debug to say it has connected

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('init','init-yes');

    logger.debug("Socket.on has connected");
    logger.log('debug', 'This is the debug');

    ...
```

but nothing appears in the console. I checked out the [git page](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) but still seem to be not understanding something.

**EDIT**
As was suggested I updated the logger creation to:

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({ level : 'debug' })
  ]
});
```

but I'm still not getting the logger.debug("Message here") to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The [fine manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#using-logging-levels) states: *"note that the default level of a transport is `info`"*.

Since you don't set the log level for your transport, any messages with a level below `info` (like `debug`) won't get shown.

To fix this:

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({ level : 'debug' })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Would that be new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'debug' })  ?

Comment: @mario that would also work, but I find that notation pretty horrible so I left out the parentheses.

Comment: I tried it and got a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. Any clue why?

Comment: @mario that doesn't sound like it's caused by Winston.

Comment: I got the error to go away but nothing is being outputted still.

Comment: And you're not redirecting/piping the output of your app? Or, to rephrase: how are you running your app? Do you see anything when you replace the calls to `logger.*()` with `console.log(...)`? Are you sure your logging statements are actually being reached?

Comment: No, at least I don't believe I am. And console.log() did not output anything either.

Comment: If `console.log()` isn't showing either, then either that code path isn't getting reached or you start your app in such a way that console output is just not being shown.

Comment: The weird thing is that some of the code works. But when I get to certain parts it dies on me as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648727/node-js-with-socket-io-winston-logger-not-outputting-debug/30651473?noredirect=1#comment49494647_30651473

Comment: I was hoping to use the debugging to get some better answers but no luck so far.

Comment: You don't happen to have `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)` somewhere in your code so any errors that are occurring are being ignored?

Comment: No sir, just checked.

Comment: Opps, I meant I had described it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713635/node-js-with-socket-io-long-polling-fails-and-throws-code1-messagesessi

Comment: @mario I have zero knowledge about IIS so can't help you there I'm afraid.